# Spring integration: download file for each update on it from FTPS server

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration.

In the Remote FTPS server, same file will be updated every time. Source system is not ready to create new file every time.

for everyupdate of the file. i need to download file and process it.

Require help to create filter to listen to every file update.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound) in the `filter` attribute and a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` in the `local-filter` attribute.

These filters, as well as persisting state so it lives beyond the current execution, also compare the modified time.

However, you need to be very careful updating a file server-side, rather than replacing it with a new one for each update. It is entirely possible (and even likely) to fetch a partially updated file (fetch the file before the writer has finished updating it).